# How to prevent a HttpUnauthorizedResult(401) from redirecting to login controller on my Api endpoint

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication

I have a web application which provides an API in addition to the actual website.
I have forms authentication enabled in my application...

Now my problem is in my API endpoints returning a `HttpUnauthorizedResult` redirects me to the login page....

How can I prevent the redirection from happening and just have a 401 status returned?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forms authentication: disable redirect to the login page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839406/forms-authentication-disable-redirect-to-the-login-page)

Comment: solution
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3978334/asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-does-a-302-redirect-when-the-user-is-not-authori

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is fixed (as of March 30th):

https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/15